# Accessing specific DOM Element? (Chrome Ext) Detailed w/ code

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I'm trying to, after a name is entered, search the results and see if a professor matches up.

The website:  https://www.ratemyprofessors.com/campusRatings.jsp?sid=45

Click Profs and you can see how you can type something in and it will filter responses. For now, I'm just trying to fiddle with those default profs listed.

My code in console to get back an array of those 20 profs is:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.result-list:last-of-type > ul > li')
```

Which works. It returns:

```
(20) [li, li, li, li, li, li, li, li, li, li, li, li, li, li, li, li, li, li, li, li]
```

Then 
I can dive deeper to access the "name" and <\a href .. tag with a link using it.

However, when I go into my chrome extension it doesn't work. With a console.log I get back:

```
[]
```

What's up? How can I access it? Previously had a similiar issue and it was because the content was running on a "frame" or something, and I had to add something like this to my code: (NOTE - From a different thing, despite similiar naming)

```
var page = top.frames["TargetContent"].document;
```

Manifest:

```
{
  "name": "RMP",
  "description": "Work in Progress",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "version": "0.8",
  "icons": { 
    "16": "icon16.png",
    "48": "icon48.png",
    "128": "icon128.png" 
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "http://*/",
    "https://*/"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Click me!"
  }
}
```

Background page

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "content_script.js"});
});
```

Content Script

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        pageLoaded(this);
    }
}

function pageLoaded(page){

    var listArray = page.response.querySelectorAll('.result-list:last-of-type > ul > li')


    console.log(listArray);
    //var xmldoc = page.responseXML;
    //var root = xmldoc.getElementsBuTagName()
}

xhr.open('GET', 'https://www.ratemyprofessors.com/campusRatings.jsp?sid=45');
xhr.responseType = 'document';
xhr.send();
```